# Adding a loess line to a ts.plot

Tags: r, plot, time-series

Assume the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(RCurl)
x <- getURL("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/aronlindberg/dfa0115f1d80b84ebd48b3ed52f9c5ac/raw/3abf0f280a948d6273a61a75415796cc103f20e7/growth_data.csv")
data <- read.csv(text = x)
data <- data[,2:20]

data[cbind(FALSE, t(apply(data[,-1], 1, function(z) duplicated(z)
 & z >= max(z))))] <- NA

ts.plot(t(data)+2, gpars = list(col = ggplot2::alpha("black", 0.5),
 ylim = c(0.5, 500), xlim = c(2, 20), xlab = "Years", 
 ylab = "Cumulative Numbers"), log = 'y')
```

How can I add a red `loess` line to this plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the modified question, we further modified the code shown there to read the URL directly in `read.csv` and to use `adjustcolor` from the base of R and then add the red loess line as shown.  No packages are used.

```
u <- "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/aronlindberg/dfa0115f1d80b84ebd48b3ed52f9c5ac/raw/3abf0f280a948d6273a61a75415796cc103f20e7/growth_data.csv"
data <- read.csv(u)[, 2:20]
data[cbind(FALSE, t(apply(data[,-1], 1, function(z) duplicated(z)
 & z >= max(z))))] <- NA

data2 <- data + 2

ts.plot(t(data2), gpars = list(col = adjustcolor("black", 0.5),
 ylim = c(0.5, 500), xlim = c(2, 20), xlab = "Years", 
 ylab = "Cumulative Numbers"), log = 'y')

s <- na.omit(stack(data2))
s$years <- as.integer(s$ind)
lo <- loess(values ~ years, s)
lines(fitted(lo) ~ years, s, col = "red", lwd = 2)
```

giving:

[image: screenshot]

### Old

You are not going to be able to use loess with so few points but here is an example using the builtin `mdeaths` and `ldeaths`.  Note that grDevices, which is a base package, has adjustcolor so you don't need to use ggplot2 to get alpha.

```
lo.m <- fitted(loess(mdeaths ~ time(mdeaths)))
lo.l <- fitted(loess(ldeaths ~ time(ldeaths)))

ts.plot(mdeaths, ldeaths, lo.m, lo.l, 
  gpars = list(col = adjustcolor(1:2, 0.5), lty = c(1, 1, 2, 2)))
```

Comment: @g-grothendieck -- I've updated the dataset with more data points. I've tried to translate from other datasets using similar code as yours, but it never seems to work on my own data...

Comment: Have revised answer to handle new data provided.